# Android: convenient method for parsing this kind of string

Tags: android, parsing

I have the following string:

```
 {
 "id":398225253590019,
 "zip":"11375",
 "street":"70-30 Austin St.",
 "state":"NY",
 "longitude":-73.845858172784,
 "latitude":40.720457257566,
 "country":"United States",
 "city":"Forest Hills"
 }
```

Please can anyone suggest me a convenient method for parsing it so that I can make a single object of the various components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

...
...

String jsonstring = "{
 "id":398225253590019,
 "zip":"11375",
 "street":"70-30 Austin St.",
 "state":"NY",
 "longitude":-73.845858172784,
 "latitude":40.720457257566,
 "country":"United States",
 "city":"Forest Hills"
 }";

JSONObject jObject = null;
try{
    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
catch(JSONException e) {
    //Json parse error usually
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

You can parset the String into JSONObject. Look the example of [JSONTokenizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html)

Answer (score 1):

That format is called json:

1.You can first create an object (Say "Object") with variables id,zip,country etc and getters and setters.

2.Download [Link for jackson.](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Download)

3.Import the library to your project.

Then just two lines of code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object object = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
```

This Object class will contain the values...

[Jackson Tutorial.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/)